# How to add custom Request type to Express?

Tags: typescript-typings

I want to add custom Request type to express.

There is way to just extend Request. But this way I have to check is auth undefined.

I cant find how to use AuthorizedRequest with app.get('/path/, ...)

How can I declare AuthorizedRequest properly?

```
// need to check undefined, auth can not exists so i cant remove "?"
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface Request {
        auth?: {
            test: string
        }
    }
}

// error with routing app.get(...)
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface AuthorizedRequest<P extends Params = ParamsDictionary> extends Request<P> {
        auth: {
            test: string
        }
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

> "- error TS2769: No overload matches this call."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create `./typings/index.d.ts`
2. Set tsconfig: `"typeRoots": ["./typings", "./node_modules/@types"]`

index.d.ts example:

```js
type Params = {
    test1: {
        test2: string
    },
    test3: number
}

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request extends Params {}
    }
}

declare module 'express' {
    export type ExtendableRequest = Request<any, any, any, any> & 
}

export {}
```